# iOS push notification issue It's working some time and not working sometime

Tags: php, ios, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have checked my code by running from URL it's working fine while I am trying from the browser. but it's not working with the curl code and I can not find the solution. `curl_error` gives nothing. I have read that "devices won't always connect to the same public IP address for notifications. " but what is the solution for that Please suggest what is wrong with the curl code/ other issues possibilities.

Here is the curl code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, BASE_URL .'api-v2/admin_notification_cron.php');
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

And `admin_notification_cron.php` file fetch data from the database and call the sendNotification function after fetching 20 data from database every 1 Minuit

Below is the `sendNotification` function code:

```
    function sendToIphone($deviceToken, $data)
    {

    $data['push_image'] = (($data['push_image']!='')?PHOTO_URL.'push/'.$data['push_image']:'');   

    $passphrase = '';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();

    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-dev-cert.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    $type = ($data['type']!='')?$data['type']:'0';

    if ($data['message']=='add_job' || $data['message']=='process') {
        //$sound = 'newrequest.mp3';
        $sound = 'default';
    } else {
        $sound = 'default';
    }


    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => stripslashes($final_message),
        'title' => APP_TITLE,
        'job_id' => $data['job_id'],
        'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
        'created'=> $data['created'],
        'type'=> $type,
        'sound' => $sound,
        "mutable-content"=> 1,
        "category"=> "rich-apns",
        "image-url"=> $data['push_image'],
        'badge' => intval($badge)

    );
    $body['att'] = array('id' => $data['push_image']);

    $payload = json_encode($body);

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    if (!$result) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are some thumb rules to implement `APNS`.

- Curl connection should be closed after delivered `notification`.
- You have to wait until your previous `notification` was not
  delivered.

> If you are executing all code in loop then some notification delivered
>   and rest of notification will be discarded.

To fix your issue you have put some delay between two `notification` triggered or fire `notification` after previous `notification` delivered.

**OR**

You can use Third party Notification tools

[FCM](https://gist.github.com/rolinger/d6500d65128db95f004041c2b636753a)

[OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference)

It will manage automatically.